# Showing a messagebox from within a TableRowGroup inherited class

Tags: c#, wpf, messagebox

I have a class that inherits from TableRowGroup to extend the TableRowGroup's functionality. This works perfectly fine, the issue i am having is when I try to show a message box from this class. The class acts like nothing in the code ever happenned and just shows the basics coming from the xaml.

Is there anything special concerning MessageBox called from within a class like this?

Here is how I call my MessageBox, it's pretty basic:

```
MessageBox.Show(message, "Title", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
```

Comment: `The class acts like nothing in the code ever happenned and just shows the basics coming from the xaml.` I'm not sure what this means.

Comment: It's a bit hard to explain, so a table row group contains multiple lines and these lines have templates. My application shows the correct amount of lines, using the right template but with no information. Just like if every line was empty.

Comment: Yes but what has table row group have to do with MessageBox?

Comment: I am trying to show a MessageBox from within my class that inherits from TableRowGroup.

Comment: Did you already debug the code? Is the line where the messagebox should be shown really reached?

Comment: Yes it is reached. If I remove the line "MessageBox.Show(etc.)" it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be wrong but I think you are messing something by doing things in different UI threads (MessageBox is from the standard Windows Forms and TableRowGroup is from WPF). Try this:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MessageBox.Show(message, "Title", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning));
```

I had the same issue with one of my colleague and it solved the problem

If someone can give some precision in the comments of this answer to enlighten me on WPF vs Windows Forms threads, you are welcome ;).